# How to change the dropdown option on a product page?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, product-attribute

I want to change the dropdown option on the product page.
Like there is a dropdown of size and I want that dropdown to change into the image icon of small, medium and large.
And when I click on the size option say small the related color images will appear below just like the default functionality of the magento.
Can anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done in Magento. Luckily you dont have to code for it. There are extensions available for it. The links for some of the extension supporting this feature are

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-1.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-for-custom-options.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-options-swatches.html

Comment: By reading the description it shows that I have to create a color for these with myself. does these extentions get the colors which are already given in the products at the time of products creation.

Comment: Which extension did you refer ??

Comment: The first two. Both had the custom option tab in the backend. I didn't install it yet, but it shows in the description.

Comment: please install the free extension and try it yourself. It pretty much covers your requirement

Comment: I install the free one and yeah it shows me the option but not as I want. It is not following the default flow infact it shows all the required options at once and I want the color option after clicking on the size of the products not before.

Comment: for that you need to use configurable products. and you need to do modification in your template file